# How should I handle forms in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I'm studying CakePHP. I read a CakePHP book, and web tutorials, but I still don't get some basic things:

I see people always create a form in View with `$form->create`. Can I use an HTML form like normal, or must do exactly like people do?

When a form is created in login.ctp with this code:

```
echo $form->create('User', array('method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'login'));     
echo $form->input('email');
echo $form->input('password');
echo $form->input(array('type' => 'submit'));
echo $form->end('Login');
```

When I click the submit button, will the data be passed to the function `login()` in the Controller class?

**Edited :**

I tried this :

```
<?php
$this->Form->create("Test");
$this->Form->input("stuId",array('class'=>'inputField', 'placeholder'=>'SVxxxxxxxx'));
$this->Form->input("stuName",array('class'=>'inputField', 'name'=>'stuName'));
$this->Form->end();
?>
```

But it show nothing ? what is the problem :(

Answer (score 3):

*But it show nothing ? what is the problem :(*

You have to use `echo` as in your first code snippet:

```
echo $this->Form->create("Test");
echo ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML for anything you want, but you'd be losing a big advantage of the CakePHP framework. The Cake HTML and form helpers help to future-proof your code. You also get the benefit of Cake's implementation of best practices in web coding. I fully recommend using those helpers.

The form data is passed to `$this->request->data`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the parameters will be passed to `login` method.

I see `$form` being used in the form there, it appears you are using older version of cakephp (if `$form` has been instantiated with `$this->Form` then you are fine)

The FormHelper does lot of `automagic` for us and it also provides us means for added security.

I would reckon you to go with [The Blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html)